# What can prevent installed packages in AWS user-data from being accessible in an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I created an AWS CloudFormation stack that is running successfully. This is to use custom EC2 instance for AWS batch, which will have the necessary docker setup to pull from a private repository.

Here is how the user-data looks like (I made it simple to just install docker in an Amazon Linux AMI):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

--==MYBOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"

packages:
- docker

runcmd:
- service docker start
- systemctl enable docker
- usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
--==MYBOUNDARY==--
```

However, when I create an instance from this launch template and access it (through SSH for example), running `docker version` shows:

```
-bash: docker: command not found
```

Which means that the installation (or the setup) in user-data wasn't performed.

Here is the full template if it can help identify what I missed:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  SubnetIDs:
    Description: Subnet IDs used by Batch compute environment
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
  SecurityGroupIDs:
    Description: Security Group IDs used by Batch compute environment
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>"
Resources:
  BatchDemoLaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: !Sub 'demo_batch_launch_template_${AWS::StackName}'
      LaunchTemplateData:
        UserData:
          Fn::Base64:
            !Sub |
              MIME-Version: 1.0
              Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

              --==MYBOUNDARY==
              Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"

              packages:
              - docker

              runcmd:
              - service docker start
              - systemctl enable docker
              - usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
              --==MYBOUNDARY==--
        ImageId: "ami-04f1014c8adcfa670"
        KeyName: "my-keys"
  BatchServiceRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub 'demo_batch_service_role_${AWS::StackName}'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBatchServiceRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - batch.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
  BatchComputeRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub 'demo_batch_compute_role_${AWS::StackName}'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AllowSecretsManager
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:1234567890:secret:dockerhub-secret-abcdef'
  BatchComputeInstanceProfile:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
      - Ref: BatchComputeRole
  ComputeEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment
    Properties:
      ComputeEnvironmentName: !Sub 'demo_batch_compute_environment_${AWS::StackName}'
      Type: MANAGED
      State: ENABLED
      ServiceRole: !Ref BatchServiceRole
      ComputeResources:
        Type: EC2
        MinvCpus: 0
        DesiredvCpus: 2
        MaxvCpus: 5
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroupIDs
        LaunchTemplate:
          LaunchTemplateId: !Ref BatchDemoLaunchTemplate
        Subnets: !Ref SubnetIDs
        InstanceRole: !Ref BatchComputeInstanceProfile
        InstanceTypes:
          - optimal
        Tags: {"Name" : "Batch demo private container registry compute environment"}
  JobQueue:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobQueue
    Properties:
      JobQueueName: !Sub 'demo_batch_job_queue_${AWS::StackName}'
      ComputeEnvironmentOrder:
        - Order: 1
          ComputeEnvironment: !Ref ComputeEnvironment
      State: ENABLED
      Priority: 1
      Tags: {"Name" : "Batch demo private container registry job queue"}
```

**UPDATES:**

When looking at the cloud-init log in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log (thanks @mark-b for the pro tip), I can see that Docker was installed, but not the setup commands in the `runcmd` section:

```
...
... Routes and SHA stuff
...

Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 running 'modules:config' at Wed, 26 Apr 2023 17:08:35 +0000. Up 36.55 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 running 'modules:final' at Wed, 26 Apr 2023 17:08:39 +0000. Up 40.70 seconds.
Amazon Linux 2023 repository                    1.5 MB/s |  13 MB     00:08
Amazon Linux 2023 Kernel Livepatch repository    20 kB/s | 155 kB     00:07
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Wed Apr 26 17:09:26 2023.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                 Arch    Version                     Repository    Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 docker                  x86_64  20.10.17-1.amzn2023.0.6     amazonlinux   39 M
Installing dependencies:
 containerd              x86_64  1.6.19-1.amzn2023.0.1       amazonlinux   31 M
 iptables-libs           x86_64  1.8.8-3.amzn2023.0.2        amazonlinux  401 k
 iptables-nft            x86_64  1.8.8-3.amzn2023.0.2        amazonlinux  183 k
 libcgroup               x86_64  3.0-1.amzn2023.0.1          amazonlinux   75 k
 libnetfilter_conntrack  x86_64  1.0.8-2.amzn2023.0.2        amazonlinux   58 k
 libnfnetlink            x86_64  1.0.1-19.amzn2023.0.2       amazonlinux   30 k
 libnftnl                x86_64  1.2.2-2.amzn2023.0.2        amazonlinux   84 k
 pigz                    x86_64  2.5-1.amzn2023.0.3          amazonlinux   83 k
 runc                    x86_64  1.1.4-1.amzn2023.0.1        amazonlinux  3.1 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  10 Packages

Total download size: 74 M
Installed size: 287 M
Downloading Packages:
(1/10): libnfnetlink-1.0.1-19.amzn2023.0.2.x86_ 105 kB/s |  30 kB     00:00
(2/10): pigz-2.5-1.amzn2023.0.3.x86_64.rpm      271 kB/s |  83 kB     00:00
(3/10): libnftnl-1.2.2-2.amzn2023.0.2.x86_64.rp 2.3 MB/s |  84 kB     00:00
(4/10): runc-1.1.4-1.amzn2023.0.1.x86_64.rpm    5.8 MB/s | 3.1 MB     00:00
(5/10): libnetfilter_conntrack-1.0.8-2.amzn2023 889 kB/s |  58 kB     00:00
(6/10): libcgroup-3.0-1.amzn2023.0.1.x86_64.rpm 1.6 MB/s |  75 kB     00:00
(7/10): iptables-libs-1.8.8-3.amzn2023.0.2.x86_ 4.6 MB/s | 401 kB     00:00
(8/10): iptables-nft-1.8.8-3.amzn2023.0.2.x86_6 2.3 MB/s | 183 kB     00:00
(9/10): docker-20.10.17-1.amzn2023.0.6.x86_64.r  14 MB/s |  39 MB     00:02
(10/10): containerd-1.6.19-1.amzn2023.0.1.x86_6 8.4 MB/s |  31 MB     00:03
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                            17 MB/s |  74 MB     00:04
```

Looking at the `/var/lib/cloud/instances/<instance-id>/user-data.txt` content I can see that the correct user-data script was uploaded (the one I mentioned before).

---

I've been in this for a bit too long and would be grateful for fresh eyes and opinions. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the cloud-init log (cloud-init is what runs the user-data script) in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` for any errors?

Comment: Thanks @MarkB for the tip on the logs. I updated accordingly. It looks like the install of Docker was correctly done, but none of the `runcmd` commands!

Comment: Is that the entire log? there's nothing in the logs about the `runcmd` at all? Also, I think you need an extra space before each `-` character in the user-data, per the example here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: You didn't add the `runcmd` stuff AFTER you created the EC2 instance did you? If you launched the instance, then modified the user-data later, it's not going to actually execute the user-data again. You would have to delete the instance and launch a new one.

Comment: You're right, adding a space at the end of the runcmd block solved the issue. Not sure why! To answer your second question, no I didn't add it after the launch, all of this was run before the launch of the instance (I ensured that by using a CloudFormation template)

Comment: A space a the end doesn't sound like what I was saying to do. You should post your findings as an answer so it is clear what you did to fix it, to help others that come here looking for an answer.